# Enforce an Edge to connect two distinct vertex classes

Tags: orientdb

Suppose that I intend to define a new edge class called MyE in OrientDB and I have A, and B as the following:

```
CREATE CLASS A EXTENDS V
CREATE CLASS B EXTENDS V
CREATE CLASS myE EXTENDS E
```

Can I enforce a kind of schematic constraint that restricts myE records source and target to A and B. In other words, I want orientDB restrict myE records to only connect A's to B's: it prevents adding a record to myE when its source and target are not A and B, respectively?

for example, if I had another vertex class say C:

```
CREATE CLASS C EXTENDS V
```

and #10:3 and #11:4 were records in C and B, respectively, issuing the following command causes an error?

```
CREATE MyE FROM #10:3 TO #11:4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
create class A extends V
create class B extends V
create class myE extends E

create property myE.out LINK A
create property myE.in LINK B

create vertex A
create vertex B

create edge myE from (select from A) to (select from B)
// works

create class C extends V
create vertex C

create edge myE from (select from C) to (select from B)
// does not work
```

See [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Using-schema-with-graphs.html).

Comment: This also answers the more general question.. can one enforce the class of vertex that an edge connects to.